# react-router-dom path for main pages and side pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to display main pages and side pages. In my case, I want to separate pages with one template and pages with another template. At the moment I have a MainPages component with a header and sidebar and AccountVerificationPages without a header and sidebar.

```js
const MainPages = () => {
  // path is "/"
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div className={classes.appRoot}>
      <Sidebar />
      <div className={classes.appContent}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path={path} exact>
            <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
              <IndentedTemplate>
                <MainPage />
              </IndentedTemplate>
            </Suspense>
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${path}browse`} exact>
            <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
              <IndentedTemplate>
                <MainPage />
              </IndentedTemplate>
            </Suspense>
          </Route>
          <Route path="*">
            <div>404</div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
const AccountVerificationPages = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/reset-password/:token`} exact>
        <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
          <FullHeightTemplate>
            <ResetPasswordPage />
          </FullHeightTemplate>
        </Suspense>
      </Route>
      <Route path={`${path}/verify/:token`} exact>
        <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
          <FullHeightTemplate>
            <VerifyEmailPage />
          </FullHeightTemplate>
        </Suspense>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*">
        <div>404</div>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
<Switch>
  {/* Main pages ("/", "/home", "/profile", etc.). keeps the main template with sidebar and header */}
  <Route path="/" component={MainPages} />
  {/* Side pages keeps other template without sidebar and header */}
  <Route path="/account" component={AccountVerificationPages} />
  <Route path="*">
    <div>404</div>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

But in this case, I get the routing for the Main Pages component. How to separate routes for MainPages and for AccountVerificationPages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It looks like the issue here is an issue with the path order and specificity in the `Switch` component used to render either `MainPages` or `AccountVerificationPages`. Recall that within the `Switch` component that the  ***first*** child `Route` or `Redirect` that matches is rendered.

In your code's case, the `path="/"` path will ***always*** match and render the `MainPages` component.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/" component={MainPages} /> // <-- Always matched and rendered
  <Route path="/account" component={AccountVerificationPages} />
  <Route path="*">
    <div>404</div>
  </Route>
</Switch>
```

## Solution

Within the `Switch` path order and specificity matters. You should order the routes in inverse order of path specificity. This also removes the need for the `exact` prop in almost all cases.

Invert the paths for `MainPages` and `AccountVerificationPages` components. "/account" is more specific than "/" and should tried to be matched first. You'll need to also remove the `"*"` wildcard route since it can't be matched because `"/"` will *always* match and render. This is ok though because both `MainPages` and `AccountVerificationPages` both already handle unhandled route paths.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/account" component={AccountVerificationPages} />
  <Route path="/" component={MainPages} />
</Switch>
```

...

```
const MainPages = () => {
  // path is "/"
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div className={classes.appRoot}>
      <Sidebar />
      <div className={classes.appContent}>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${path}browse`}>
            <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
              <IndentedTemplate>
                <MainPage />
              </IndentedTemplate>
            </Suspense>
          </Route>
          <Route path={path}>
            <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
              <IndentedTemplate>
                <MainPage />
              </IndentedTemplate>
            </Suspense>
          </Route>
          <Route path="*">
            <div>404</div>
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const AccountVerificationPages = () => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path={`${path}/reset-password/:token`}>
        <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
          <FullHeightTemplate>
            <ResetPasswordPage />
          </FullHeightTemplate>
        </Suspense>
      </Route>
      <Route path={`${path}/verify/:token`}>
        <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
          <FullHeightTemplate>
            <VerifyEmailPage />
          </FullHeightTemplate>
        </Suspense>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*">
        <div>404</div>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```